# How to properly create a C function (including header file)

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm trying to create my own functions in C, and then use `#include` with a header file. I know how to make the header file, and I've written the .c function. However, when I try to compile the .c, I get an error that says '[Linker error]undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'' and it fails to compile.
Then, if I try to use it in a program, it says '[Warning]no newline at end of file' and then '[Linker error]undefined reference to validf(int, int, int)'.
Can anyone help?

Function Code:

```
int validf(int current,int max, int zero)
{
    if(zero==1)
    {
        if(current>max || current<0)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input");
            return 0; 
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if(zero==0)
    {
        if(current>max || current<=0)
        {
            printf("Invalid Input");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid parameters");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Main Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "validf.h"

int main()
{
  int valid=0;
  valid=validf(4,5,0);
  printf("%d",valid);
  system("\npause");
  return 0;
}
```

Header Code:

```
#ifndef VALIDF_H_  
#define VALIDF_H_  
int validf(int current,int max,int zero);  
#endif
```

Comment: Did you write the `main` function?

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you are using Eclipse you probable have to save the file first and compile.

Comment: The code is the function that the header should add, not the code using the function. I'm using Dev C++ (i's not my fault, we have no choice).

Comment: It would be better if you post the main code also.

Comment: You code is fine and running properly..it seems its a dev c++ issue. Maybe it is not finding the file

Comment: Looking around, many people have suggested making a project, but then I would have to do that every time I want to use the header. Is that the best solution, or is there something better I can do?

Comment: *Function Code* is not in validf.h, is it?

Comment: @MrGalax1 Whether "function code" and "main code" are there in same .c file? did you try like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your program consists of 3 files:

`validf.h`  header file for `validf`. Contains declaration of `validf` function

`validf.c`  code file for `validf`. Contains definition of `validf` function.

`main.c`    contains the `main` function. You may have chosen another name for this file.

In your IDE, you should create a project that consists of these files.
You also need to configure the name of the resulting program. I am not familiar with that particular IDE, but it is usually done under `Project->Settings->Compile or Build or Link`.

This will make your IDE compile the two `.c` files and then link them into a single program.

If you dont create a project it is probable that the IDE treats each `.c` file as a different program, which will cause the errors you mention.